# WorkflowHost in a non-IIS environment... How?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

So I created a contract first workflow in 2012. I have an xamlx file which has a parallel path for each of the operations. Everything works great under IIS (Express).

However, I need to host these WCF services in an EXE rather than IIS. I have been attempting to use a WorkflowServiceHost, but no matter how I configure it, I keep getting error related to thing such as "Activity must be Set"...etc. etc.

Unfortunately a search across the web has not yielded a working WF4.5 solution. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

IIS uses a WorkflowServiceHost under the covers which is derived from the WCF ServiceHost. Just new one up with the workflow definction and open it to start listening for incoming requests.

Simple console application code.

```
var workflow = new MyWorkflow();
var serviceHost = new WorkflowServiceHost(workflow);
serviceHost.Open();
Console.WriteLine("WorkflowServiceHost is listening...");
Console.ReadLine();serviceHost.Close();
```

Related app.config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="MyWorkflow">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/MyWorkflow" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMyWorkflow"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```